# Trouble connecting tsql to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linux, t-sql, connection

I'm trying to connect to a network SQL server from a 64 bit linux machine (ubuntu).  I think I've configured my freetds.conf, odbc.ini, and odbcinst.ini correctly. But tsql gives me an error connecting.

I've tried following this link's instructions:

http://www.tryolabs.com/Blog/2012/06/25/connecting-sql-server-database-python-under-ubuntu/

Yet, the command 'tsql -H {SQL Server IP address} -p 1433 -U {username} -P {password}' gives the following output:

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Msg 18456 (severity 14, state 1) from <Sql Server Name> Line 1:
    "Login failed for user '<username>'."
Error 20002 (severity 9):
    Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

To '/usr/local/freetds/etc/freetds.conf' file, I've added:

```
[sqlserver]
    host = {SQL Server IP Address}
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

The '/etc/odbc.ini' file contains:

```
[sqlserver]
Driver      = freetds
Description = MSSQL Server
ServerName  = {SQL Server IP Address}
Port        = 1433
Trace       = No
Database    =
TDS_Version = 8.0
```

The '/etc/odbcinst.ini' file contains:

```
[freetds]
Description     = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
UsageCount      = 1
FileUsage       = 1
```

Some more details: If I use windows, MS-SQL Server uses my windows credentials to access the server.  It is also a 'trusted connection' (not sure what that means).

I've done lots of searching, and have tried putting a copy of '.freetds.conf' in the home directory as well with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trusted connection means it is authenticating through an Active Directory user. If you are using your Active Directory user here, you are asking SQL Server to authenticate a SQL Server local login and your user is an AD user. I have used the following connection string successfully for AD users:

```
'DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=servername;PORT=1433;UID=domain\\username;PWD=********;TDS_Version=8.0;Trusted_domain=Your.Domain.com;'
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked.  I also had to change the headers in my .ini files to match.